# Block Sliding Down a Plane (Perpendicular Velocity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

I'm having trouble understand the concepts for this problem. Here's the problem:

> *A block is placed on a plane inclined at angle $\theta$. The coefficient of friction between the block and the plane is $\mu = \tan \theta$. The block is given a kick so that it initially moves with speed $V $horizontally along the plane (that is, in the direction perpendicular to the direction pointing straight down the plane). What is the speed of the block after a very long time?*

We can see that $F_x = mg\sin \theta - mg\cos (\theta )\mu = 0$, if we gave the block an initial velocity *along* the plane, it should be subjected to a friction force opposite its velocity, where $f = mg \cos \theta \tan \theta = mg\sin \theta$

This however, is the answer my book gave:

> The normal force from the plane is $N = mg \cos \mu$. Therefore, the friction force on
>   the block is $N = (\tan \mu)N = mg \sin \mu$. This force acts in the direction opposite to
>   the motion. The block also feels the gravitational force of $mg \sin \theta$ pointing down the
>   plane.
>   Because the magnitudes of the friction force and the gravitational force along the
>   plane are equal, **the acceleration along the direction of motion equals the negative
>   of the acceleration in the direction down the plane. Therefore, in a small increment
>   of time, the speed that the block loses along its direction of motion exactly equals
>   the speed that it gains in the direction down the plane**. Letting v be the speed of
>   the block, and letting vy be the component of the velocity in the direction down the
>   plane, we therefore have $$v + vy = C$$
>   where $C$ is a constant. $C$ is given by its initial value, which is $V + 0 = V$ . The final value of $C$ is $V_f + V_f = 2V_f$ (where $V_f$ is the final speed of the block), because the
>   block is essentially moving straight down the plane after a very long time. Therefore,
>   $2V_f = V \rightarrow V_f = \frac{V}{2}$

I don't really understand what this is trying to say. The bolded part is what's giving me problems. I think it just may be poorly written, I think I need a clearer explanation.

Comment: I think your textbook worded the problem poorly.

Answer (score 3):

That's a nice problem - what book is it from? One can get the right answer quickly by projecting forces to the moving axis aligned with the instantaneous direction of V to find d/dt(V), and that is what the book seems to be suggesting (but in a rather obscure way).

Here is a different approach to the solution, probably more straightforward in terms of physics but requiring a bit of algebra and calculus, using coordinates (x,y) on the surface of the wedge; x is the horizontal axis, y is vertical (up the wedge).

There are three forces acting on the body: gravity $mg$, normal reaction $N$, and friction $R$. Since the motion is in the plane of the wedge the sum of forces projected to the normal direction is zero so $N=mg \cos{\theta}$. Within the plane there are two forces. First is the projection of gravity $mg \sin \theta$ directed downward. The second one is the friction force $R$. For $\mu=\tan(\theta)$ a body on inclined plane with the friction coefficient $\mu$ is on threshold of sliding; the standard analysis is given, e.g., in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction. Thus the friction force is equal to $R=N \mu = mg \cos{\theta} \tan \theta = mg \sin{\theta}$ and is directed opposite to the velocity vector.

To summarize, the motion within the plane results from action of two forces of equal magnitude $mg \sin{\theta}$, one is directed down the wedge, the other is directed opposite to the velocity vector. From that one can derive that the rate of change of the total velocity magnitude $V$ is equal to that for $V_y$. Initially the body is moving horizontally with velocity $V_0$, so $V=V_0$ and $V_y=0$. Eventually the motion vector is directed down the wedge with $V_f$, so the final values are $V=V_f$ and $V_y=-V_f$. Then it follows that $V_f-V_0=-V_f$, so $V_f=V_0/2$.

The details of the calculation are shown below:

[image]

Comment: The main problem,perhaps,that the OP was facing is why the friction force is equal to the y component of gravity minus the normal force.it is written in your answer without any explanation. Can you please elaborate the fact.thanks.

Comment: ok, added in the text of the answer, thanks for pointing out

Comment: You seem not to follow my previous comment.The real question is -why the friction force is equal in size to the y projection of the gravity minus the normal force N? which is mentioned in your second para.How did you come to that conclusion.please expand your answer on that.

Comment: Ok, I see that something was not right previously in the explanations. Now it should be correct, and hopefully it is explained clearly now.