# Static or dynamic?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, friction

Long time ago, I found a question in the book **Introduction to Classical Mechanics**-*David Morin*.
The question was

> **Sliding sideways on a plane:**
>
> A block is placed on a plane inclined at an angle $\theta$. The coefficient of friction between the block and the plane is $\mu= \tan \theta$. The block is given a kick so that it initially moves with speed $V$ horizontally along the plane (that is, in the direction perpendicular to the direction pointing straight
> down the plane). What is the speed of the block after a very long time?
>
> > $V_{\text{final}}=\frac{V}{2}$

**My questions**

1. If instead of a plane, it were a wedge (of mass M) placed on a frictionless plane will the block have the same velocity as in the previous question (if not, then what will it be)? (assume mass of block to be m)
2. Is it possible to find the time dependent position closed-form solutions for the problem in David Morin?

Any method for the above questions will be appreciated (including Hamiltonians and Lagrangians if necessary)

References:

1. [https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~rfu/notes/slideplane.pdf](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Erfu/notes/slideplane.pdf) (Contains the solution to the above problem and the trajectory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block Sliding Down a Plane (Perpendicular Velocity)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91426/)

Comment: Hi Anindya Prithvi. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 0):

Original question: The friction acts to the rear of curved motion. The horizontal speed will approach zero exponentially. Down the surface it reaches a terminal speed when the friction balances the component of gravity.  A free wedge will accelerate (away from the block), reducing the normal and friction force. The curve will be different.  Given numbers, I would use a numeric simulation for this motion.

Comment: Do you have a place for num-simulation? And what about the time dependent curve

Comment: I do simulations on an EXCEL spreadsheet. Formulas can be propagated down the page for a hundred or more steps, most all common functions are provided, and the results can be displayed on one or more graphs.

Comment: That does mean you can predict time evolution of system as well, do you have a resource where i can have a headstart with the basics? If possible, also share one sample of simulation of any mechanical/quantum/foo-bar system, Thanks