# Kinetic friction against gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

I am trying to solve this problem and I seem to misunderstand the idea of kinetic friction.

> *A block is placed on a plane inclined at angle $\theta$. The coefficient of friction between the block and the plane is $\mu = \tan \theta$. The block is given a kick so that it initially moves with speed $V $horizontally along the plane (that is, in the direction perpendicular to the direction pointing straight down the plane). What is the speed of the block after a very long time?*

I got that the kinetic friction is equal to the gravitational force along the plane which is $f = mg\sin \theta$. If you give a push horizontally (x-direction), instantly the kinetic friction is going to act on and decrease the velocity until it becomes zero. But wouldn't this kinetic friction also act along the y-direction of the plane? As the box moves in y-direction due to gravity of $mg\sin \theta$, the kinetic friction of equal magnitude will apply instantly on the opposite direction. How can the box move downwards and gain velocity when the kinetic friction will act right away as the box moves a little bit. I don't know why this box wouldn't be stuck in y-direction.

Comment: Can you put the convention, You are using for $x$ and $y $ axis.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi I'm not too sure what you mean by the convention. I am using right arrow as x axis and upper arrow as y axis, the typical one.

Comment: I mean , Are you taking the x-axis as along the inclined plane and y as perpendicular to inclined plane?

Comment: @YoungKindaichi Both should be along the inclined plane. It's a plane so you could see it as x-y plane itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block Sliding Down a Plane (Perpendicular Velocity)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91426/block-sliding-down-a-plane-perpendicular-velocity)